# Excel WEEKNUM function Return_type

Tags: excel, date, week-number

The WEEKNUM function syntax has the following arguments:

```
WEEKNUM(serial_number,[return_type])
```

Return_type     Optional. A number that determines on which day the week begins.

Please show an examples what's the difference between Return_type 2,11 and 21 ? Beacause i cant reproduce diff

Comment: difference between (2,11) & 21 is the system type and is given here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/weeknum-function-HP010343016.aspx

Comment: Functionality of 2 & 11 are same.. 2 is used for early versions of excel

Comment: Thanks it helpful because using 2 is better form me ))

Answer (score 0):

Starting point: Reed the following link:

```
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/weeknum-HP005209337.aspx
```

and try with 5/5/12. You have 19 / 19 / **18**...